# File corrupted simply by opening and saving with no changes

Tags: c#, epplus

Working on some code to update a spreadsheet but I noticed the isolated act of opening the spreadsheet and saving it corrupts it, resulting in the message
"We found a problem with some content in''.  Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"

This can be replicated by the following code

```
FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo("mysheet.xlsm");
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
{
    excel.Save();
}
```

The resulting file also shrinks from around 3MB to 2MB in the process.

Seems like this should be pretty straight forward but I must be missing something crucial.

Comment: Did you raise the issue with epplus support?

Comment: It may be that your spreadsheet contains some content that's not supported by EPPlus (it doesn't cover 100% of what you can do with Excel). Have you tried with a different / more basic spreadsheet?

Comment: @mjwillis I looked at the [http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions](discussion forum) but it didn't look all that active so I came here first.  I could try that route as well...

Comment: @Chris your codeplex link is broken

Comment: @mjwills whoops had the formatting backwards I guess http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions is the link but its primarily threads of questions posed with no responses.

Comment: @Pete  The same thing happens if I create a blank .xlsm document in excel, then run it through the code to open/save.  It does not happen with blank .xlsx document.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get to the bottom of the problem and switched to the Interop library.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCAIMER**: This isn't an answer, but I want to post some code

I've tried to reproduce your problem, but with no luck. Steps as follows:

I've created a spreadsheet manually in Excel 2010. The text in cell A1 of Sheet1 simply reads "Hello". I've also added a code module in the macro editor (Alt-F11) with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Foo()

    MsgBox "Hello World", vbOKOnly, "Foo!"

End Sub
```

I then saved this as a macro-enabled spreadsheet (C:\Temp\Book1.xlsm)

In Visual Studio I then created a C# console app and added the EPPlus package from NuGet. The main method looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Book1.xlsm")))
    {
        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

When I debug this it executes without issue.

Have you checked permissions on the folder you're saving to and forced a refresh of your EPPlus package?

Comment: I appreciate the help..

I tried your example and it worked ok, then repeated mine with the blank document and it failed again.  Then tried another where I added "Hello" and that failed, so it seems to require a macro to be present for the .xlsm to save correctly.  This kind of validates a previous experiment that failed where I had copied a text only worksheet from the problem workbook and run it through the code, and that failed too.

So we can definitely save the .xlsm, but it may be difficult to find what part of my document is causing the problem...